# How can I call a function in my as file from my fla without linking it?

Tags: actionscript-3

I've got an .as file in the same folder of my FLA file.

I'd like to call trigger a function from an action frame of my as file.

My as file is like that :

```
package {
        import flash.display.MovieClip;
        import flash.text.TextField;
        import flash.events.MouseEvent;

        public class Game extends MovieClip {
            var words:Array = new Array; //a mini database to hold the words
            var rand1:int;var rand2:int; //variables used for randomization
            var scramble_Array:Array = new Array; //array used to scramble the word
            var unscramble_Array:Array = new Array; //array to hold the unscrambled word
            var temp:String; //temporary variable

            var pauser:Boolean; //used to pause the game


        public function Game() {
            getword();
            checker=new button_chk;addChild(checker);
            checker.x=150;checker.y=400;
            checker.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, check_answer);
        }
        ...
...
```

How can I call the function "Game" in my FLA file using action frame ?

I've tried to do

```
Game();
```

But it says that one argument is missing.

Answer (score 0):

It is a class constructor, you don't just call it, you instantiate (create a new instance of) the class with the **new** operator:

```
import Game;

var aGame:Game = new Game;
```